# How to store content into iOS Notes native

Tags: ios

I have a swift iOS project. In a scenario, I want to save some content into iPhone "Notes" application programmatically. I couldn't find any APIs or program to save text content into iOS "Notes" native application programmatically. If I missed and someone knows about it, please guide me the program.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge Apple has not provided any APIs to interact with Notes application as of now. So it's not possible currently for you to 'Create/Save' content to Notes app.

Comment: Do you have any Apple developer Link that mention this thing?